# LPR command not printing Barcode of type 128 in .net core on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, itext, .net-core, lpr

I am creating PDF file in .net core by using `iTextSharp`.

I have used `Barcode128` class of `iTextSharp.text.pdf` for adding bar-code to my PDF file.

For printing PDF in .net core, I am using following code:

```
string fileName = @"/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Test/test123.pdf";

Process objP = new Process();

objP.StartInfo.FileName = "lpr";

string printerName = "Label_Printer";

objP.StartInfo.Arguments = " -P " + printerName + " " + fileName;

objP.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

objP.Start();
```

If my PDF file contains, plain text, it prints fine.
But if it contains bar-code, it prints a blank page.

What is wrong over here?
Is LPR exe of Ubuntu not compatible to work with Bar-code type 128?

Comment: Please share your PDF file.

Comment: You can download PDF file, by using following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxbvneGO31WMSVQ5dmprZk55QTA/view?usp=sharing